# Subsonic 2.2: Update only works for some fields?

Tags: c#, .net, database, sql-server-2005, subsonic

```
 MyTable.Update(long.Parse(id), txtLocation.Text, txtCode.Text, locale, 
                           chkAvailable.Checked, DateTime.Now);
```

Neither chkAvailable.Checked or DateTime.Now cause an update but changing the other fields do...

What's going on?

I'm using SQL Server 2005. .NET 3.5 SP1

Rob

Comment: This is the static "Object Data Source" stuff I believe - can you set a breakpoint and be sure that all fields are set properly? It's hard to say what's going on without knowing a bit more like what type of DB you're using, etc.

Comment: Hi Rob, thanks for the reply. Yes it is static object datasource I've followed it through in the Debugger to item.Save() and all the props are set properly. It's SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try another way ?? like

Object obj = new Object();
obj.field = xxx;
obj.field = xxxx;

obj.Save();

Other question ? What the database do you using ??? I´m asking because not all the databases have the type boolean and you set in the line "chkAvailable.Checked"

Comment: It's SQL2005 and it uses the bit type, this works fine for insert so I don't see why it wouldn't work in this case.

Comment: I never use the bit type because my projects have to run in SqlServer oracle and mySql . But I agree with you, should be work.....